# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited

Tags: python, discord.py

main.py:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from event import Event
from discord.ext import commands
import sqlite3
import os

TOKEN = 'token lol'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+', intents=discord.Intents.all())
bot.add_cog(Event(bot))

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

event.py:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import sqlite3

class Event(commands.Cog):
   def __init__(self, bot):
      self.bot = bot

   @commands.Cog.listener()
   async def on_ready(self):
      db = sqlite3.connect("eco.sqlite")
      cursor = db.cursor()
      cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eco (usr_id INTERGER, usr_sp INTERGER)")
      print("bot ready")

   @commands.Cog.listener()
   async def on_message(self, message):
      if message.author.bot:
         return
      
      author = message.author
      db = sqlite3.connect("eco.sqlite")
      cursor = db.cursor()
      cursor.execute(f"SELECT usr_id FROM eco WHERE usr_id = {author.id}")
      result = cursor.fetchone()
      if result is None:
         sql = (f"INSERT INTO eco (usr_id, usr_sp) VALUES (?, ?)")
         val = (author.id, 750)
         cursor.execute(sql, val)
      
      db.commit()
      cursor.close()
      db.close()
```

output:

```
e:\DiscordBot\Bot\main.py:11: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
  bot.add_cog(Event(bot))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2023-02-16 19:00:45 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2023-02-16 19:00:46 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 87bb94ab78d04363a6b25ccb433e5993).
```

I tried to look for a solution to this and found nothing
someone help me pls

Answer (score 1):

The error basically tells you what you need to do. `bot.add_cog` is now a coroutine function which you need `await` keyword for calling it.

Also, consider switching the `add_cog` method's location into your `event.py`:

```py
# under your event.py, outside of class
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Event(bot))
```

This would be a cleaner way to rewrite.

Comment: thx, but what do you mean by "switching the `add_cog` method's location into your `event.py`"

Comment: since you need to add your cog to your bot, then it's better to have a `setup` function under each cog class to add the cog to the bot.